# Automate wget request requiring MASSL password

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, wget

We're upgrading our JBoss server to only allow MASSL requests (i.e. requests that require client and server certs in order to be successful).

We use wget to call into a simple servlet on this server:

```
wget -O - --no-check-certificate "https://server.com/app/do/something" 2>&1
```

This wget call is fired automatically every 4 hours.

Since MASSL has been introduced, we now pass a cert over:

```
wget -O - --ca-certificate=cert.pem --certificate=othercert.pem "https://server.com/app/do/something" 2>&1
```

This prompts for password which we enter and overall it works fine.

**Problem:**
We want to automate this wget call but we can't automatically input the password. For example, when the script containing this wget is called every four hours, we don't want it to prompt for password but to automatically pass it over.

I've tried piping it through:

```
echo password | wget ...

wget ... | password
```

passing `username` and `password` parameters:

```
wget ... --user=myuser --password=mypassword ...
```

and also tried using the `yes` command, to no avail.

Any suggestions? Are there any alternatives to wget that may work?